Can you help me find this Japanese font?
I've been looking everywhere on google for all day but couldn't find it, which is why I am asking here. Any help is much appreciated

Try using likefont.com - it can automatically identify CJK fonts.

The closest I got is Inziu IosevkaCC SC Bold Italic
